# Weird Armature Deformation

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

When I apply an armature to a character (with automatic weight), my character gets a really weird bend on any parts of its body. I have rigged a character before, so I don't know how it went wrong. I've repeated the process multiple times and got the same results. I even tried exporting it as a mesh and loading it into a new blender file, but I still get the distortions. I have the blender file available, but don't know how to share it, so if you need it, tell me how.

EDIT: Here's the file: http://pasteall.org/blend/23791. The bones are in place, but the modifiers need to be applied before applying the bones. (With automatic weights.)

[image: Arm bend] [image: Leg bend].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you *[can](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/weird-armature-deformation#comment4522_2674)* rig with a *Mirror* modifier on your mesh, it is best in your case here to just apply it, you won't be able to rig your character properly if it is active with your current naming scheme. You might also want to then change your *Pivot center* from *3D Cursor* to *Bounding Box Center* by using <kbd>,</kbd> *(comma)* or selecting it from the view header, having it set to rotate around the *3D Cursor* can also lead to some weird behaviour when trying to pose if you don't know what to expect. You might also want to recalculate your mesh normals at this point with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]

…and finally, try again..

[image]

For some help in parenting the mesh to the armature, you can refer to [How can I automatically generate vertex groups for an armature?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/782/how-can-i-automatically-generate-vertex-groups-for-an-armature). It wouldn't hurt to add some more geometry (loopcuts) to the arms and legs to help the character deform better either.

Comment: I found out that all my normals were inside out. i recalculated them and tried the armature again, and it worked. I couldn't answer my own question because of my low rep.

Comment: @Ripspace Ah, there were several problems including that. _Unless_ you know what your are doing, it is not considered wise to rig with a mirror modifier on your mesh.

Comment: I applied the mirror mod as well. Changing the pivot point is a good thing you pointed out as well.

Comment: @Ripspace Ok, I was working with the file you uploaded so I pretty much covered all the possible reasons why it could have happened.

Comment: @Ripspace Actually, keeping the Mirror modifier is OK as long as bone naming is symmetrical (with `.L` or `.R` suffix) and no shape key is involved. This armature's bone naming could be much better.

Comment: @Adhi Instead of getting into the technicalities, I thought it best to have OP just play it safe and get it to work. I added it to the answer.

Comment: @iKlsR No mere technicality. I just fix bone naming, redo automatic weighting, and the result is a decent start. I'll just point out the importance of **proper bone naming** for automatic weighting, then.

Comment: I've read all of the comments. I plan on renaming the bones; I just needed it to work first. I'm making a video game, so naming is actually very important to me.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the steps you've listed here but pressing " , " (comma) doesn't appear to do anything and pressing ctrl+n just asks if I want to reload the startup file

Comment: @ColinRCasto Then try using the button I outline in the answer and selecting the pivot point that you want and to recalculate normals, you need to be in _Edit_ mode.