# Deform bones configurations produces a bad deformed beak

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

yesterday I bought the addon called "re-face!" and I have completed the rigging tutorial contained inside the package using the character that I'm creating,a bird with an humanoid face. The script uses two armatures : Body_rig and Face_rig. The first one is for the body and the second is for the face. I have parented the Face_rig to CTRL_head bone,as the tutorial says. The eyes are parented to the DIF_head bone and all other TRK* bones to the CTRL_head bone. I can add more bones to the Face_rig armature,but I can't delete the default bones. If I do it,I get one error that says that the deleted bone is not present and the script does not generate the facial rig. Also,the script generates two armatures,on the first one there are the deform bones and the control bones,but on the second the deform bones disappear. Problem is that when I do the automatic weights,the beak is deformed bad. This deform bones configuration :

[image: 1] 
[image: 2]

after the automatic weights,produce this outuput :

[image: 3]

and this :

[image: 4]

generates a situation like this :

[image]

as you can see,in any case,the beak is deformed very bad. How can I fix it ? thanks.

Comment: could you please accept the answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the answer found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/792/2517). This will give you two options to fix this:

1. Modify the weight painting to tweak what parts of your mesh are
   affected by each group.
2. Create empty vertex groups and then do
   the assignment manually, this will give you a bit more control over
   how your groups are created as you can see it on the fly and edit it
   further.